# How to capture multiple responses on one single POST request using Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, captcha

I am trying to web scrape [this](https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx) website and download the pdf files available when you complete the whole lifecycle of this website. I am using Scrapy for this. I am having some trouble with **capturing the captcha at the right time**.

This site is an ASPX webpage and uses '**Viewstates**' to keep track of each POST requests. Now, if you go through this site, you'll understand that whenever you fill any dropdown fields, it sends POST request with 'Viewstate' value to a certain URL path, which you can see in the browser console. But at the same time, it sends another GET request to another URL to fetch the "**CAPTCHA**" image. But I am not able to get this response. I don't have any idea whether using Scrapy can we capture multiple requests multiple responses at the same time.

[image]

[image]

Now, I tried to find a workaround for this issue. And I have followed almost everything mentioned in this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948326/scrapy-captcha#answer-43552496) post, but in response I am getting HTML code with javascript alert code mentioning "**Wrong text inserted, Please enter new characters shown in image textbox**". So, this solution is also not working for me.

This is my scrapy spider code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from election_data.items  import ElectionDataItem

class ElectionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'election'
    allowed_domains = ['ceo.maharashtra.gov.in']
    start_urls = ['https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx']
    dist_dict = []

    def parse(self, response):
        district = response.css('select#Content_DistrictList > option::attr(value)')[1].extract()
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET' : response.css('select#Content_DistrictList::attr(name)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
            '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
            '__VIEWSTATE' : response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : district,
            'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : ''
        }
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        request = scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], method='POST', formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.parse_assembly)
        request.meta['district'] = district
        yield request

    def parse_assembly(self, response):
        print('parse_assembly')
        assembly = response.css('select#Content_AssemblyList > option::attr(value)')[1].extract()
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET' : response.css('select#Content_AssemblyList::attr(name)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
            '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
            '__VIEWSTATE' : response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : response.meta['district'],
            'ctl00$Content$AssemblyList' : assembly,
            'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : ''
        }
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        request = scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], method='POST', formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.parse_part)
        request.meta['district'] = response.meta['district']
        request.meta['assembly'] = assembly
        yield request

    def parse_part(self, response):
        print('parse_part')
        part = response.css('select#Content_PartList > option::attr(value)')[1].extract()
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET' : response.css('select#Content_PartList::attr(name)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
            '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
            '__VIEWSTATE' : response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : response.meta['district'],
            'ctl00$Content$AssemblyList' : response.meta['assembly'],
            'ctl00$Content$PartList' : part,
            'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : ''
        }
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        request = scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], method='POST', formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.parse_captcha)
        request.meta['__VIEWSTATE'] = response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first()
        request.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first()
        request.meta['district'] = response.meta['district']
        request.meta['assembly'] = response.meta['assembly']
        request.meta['part'] = part
        yield request

    def parse_captcha(self, response):
        data_for_later = response
        request = scrapy.Request(url='https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/Captcha.aspx', callback=self.store_image)
        request.meta['__VIEWSTATE'] = response.meta['__VIEWSTATE']
        request.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = response.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION']
        request.meta['district'] = response.meta['district']
        request.meta['assembly'] = response.meta['assembly']
        request.meta['part'] = response.meta['part']
        request.meta['data_for_later'] = data_for_later
        yield request

    def store_image(self, response):
        captcha_target_filename = 'filename.png'
        # save the image for processing
        i = Image.open(BytesIO(response.body))
        i.save(captcha_target_filename)
        captcha_text = self.solve_captcha(captcha_target_filename)
        print(captcha_text)
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET' : '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
            '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
            '__VIEWSTATE' : response.meta['__VIEWSTATE'],
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION'],
            'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : response.meta['district'],
            'ctl00$Content$AssemblyList' : response.meta['assembly'],
            'ctl00$Content$PartList' : response.meta['part'],
            'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : captcha_text,
            'ctl00$Content$OpenButton': 'Open PDF'
        }
        captcha_form = response.meta['data_for_later']
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        request = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(captcha_form, method='POST', formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.get_pdfs)
        yield request

    def get_pdfs(self, response):
        # THIS IS WHERE FINAL RESPONSE IS CAPTURED
        print(response.text)

    def solve_captcha(self, image):
        image = cv2.imread(image,0)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
        close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

        result = 255 - close
        cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
        cv2.imshow('close', close)
        cv2.imshow('result', result)

        return pytesseract.image_to_string(result)
```

If you go through the above-mentioned site and fill all the form details, monitor the browser consols network tab, you'll get an idea about this problem.

Kindly guide me in how to solve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the reason I hate ASP.NET applications, it just make you go nuts while scraping. Anyways, you had everything almost perfect, except one thing

```py
def parse_captcha(self, response):
    data_for_later = response
    request = scrapy.Request(url='https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/Captcha.aspx', callback=self.store_image)
    request.meta['__VIEWSTATE'] = response.meta['__VIEWSTATE']
    request.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = response.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION']
    request.meta['district'] = response.meta['district']
    request.meta['assembly'] = response.meta['assembly']
    request.meta['part'] = response.meta['part']
    request.meta['data_for_later'] = data_for_later
    yield request
```

This comes from a response where you set the `part`, but what you do is copy the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` previous to setting the part. So you need to make sure you capture the correct states

```py
def parse_captcha(self, response):
    data_for_later = response
    request = scrapy.Request(url='https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/Captcha.aspx', callback=self.store_image)
    request.meta['__VIEWSTATE'] = response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first()
    request.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first()
    request.meta['district'] = response.meta['district']
    request.meta['assembly'] = response.meta['assembly']
    request.meta['part'] = response.meta['part']
    request.meta['data_for_later'] = data_for_later
    yield request
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks for solving my problem. It's a bit late anyway, but no problem at all, you learn all the time. Thanks once again.

Comment: Any solution for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929354/having-issue-while-downloading-all-pdf-files-on-asp-website-using-scrapy

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (yet), but a few pointers:

1. Did you have Cookies enabled? There's a ASP.NET_SessionID cookie passed around with every request on this site.
2. do the responses that you get up to requesting the captcha look ok?
3. this long sequence of requests is difficult to understand and may contain bugs that are difficult to spot. Suggest in a first step you focus first on solving the captcha only:

   - If I select only the district and fill in a wrong or a correct captcha solution, I either get a "wrong captcha" message or a "select correct details".
   - So getting to the "select correct details" is easier (fewer requests/moving parts) but already shows you whether you solved the captcha correctly, so I'd suggest you try this first and then build on this result.

Besides this your approach looks sound and has no obvious problems.

BTW: In the end it might turn out that emulating the full sequence of requests is unnecessary, it might be ok to skip to the last two requests for getting the final captcha and sending the final form submission ... but that won't help us here, just for later refactoring and making the code simpler.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. 1. Yeah, cookies are enabled default. 2. Yes, the responses I am getting up to requesting the CAPTCHA looks OK. 3. Yes, I am able to solve CAPTCHA correctly. The function I have mentioned in above code `solve_captcha` is for solving the CAPTCHA and it is working fine without no issues. The only issue I am having is finding a way to skip making a separate request for CAPTCHA, cause that's why I am getting wrong CAPTCHA image, at first place AND get the captcha image along with the last form submit request. If you have any idea about this, then let me know.

Comment: Sure, my answer is fully based on the assumption that solve_captcha works correctly. What usually goes wrong with such scrapers: the server issues some kind of token or id that's identifying the captcha you got. It seems this is what gets mixed up at some place. So did you try replicating this issue with solving the captcha and submitting an empty form?

Comment: Any solution for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929354/having-issue-while-downloading-all-pdf-files-on-asp-website-using-scrapy