# Having issue while downloading all pdf files on .asp website using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am having an issue while downloading multiple pdf files on .asp website using Scrapy. This is the URL of the website: `https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx`.

Now, if you go through the website, it sends multiple form request to the same above URL and generated the newly updated HTML content for the same page. Now, I have gone through every step, including solving the CAPTCHA and finally, I have arrived at the final step where pdfs can be downloaded.

When you fill all the form details, including CAPTCHA, you'll get to see more than one links to download the same numbers of unique pdf files. And this is where I am having the issue.

[image: PDF FILE LINKS]

Now, when you click on any links, it sends one POST request to same above URL and refreshes the page with the following javascript content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.open('ViewRoll.aspx');//]]>
</script>
```

And this above code, opens the another tab with the url `https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/ViewRoll.aspx` which shows pdf in the tab. And I want to download this pdf file.

So far, I am able to download a single pdf file with no issues using Scrapy. But the issue I have is downloading more than one pdf files. Sometimes, my below code download same pdf file twice, sometimes it downloads only one pdf file. But every time, it downloads at least one pdf file if not every other pdf files.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import cv2
import pytesseract
from io import BytesIO
from election_data.items  import ElectionDataItem
import os
from pathlib import Path

class ElectionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'election'
    allowed_domains = ['ceo.maharashtra.gov.in']
    start_urls = ['https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx']
    base_path = "D:\\Projects\\scrape_data\\data"

    def parse(self, response):
        district = response.css('select#Content_DistrictList > option::attr(value)')[1].extract()
        district_name = response.css('select#Content_DistrictList > option::text')[1].extract()
        district_path = os.path.join(self.base_path, district_name.replace(' ', '_'))
        os.mkdir(district_path)
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET' : response.css('select#Content_DistrictList::attr(name)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
            '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
            '__VIEWSTATE' : response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : district,
            'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : ''
        }
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        request = scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], method='POST', formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.parse_assembly)
        request.meta['district'] = district
        request.meta['district_path'] = district_path
        yield request

    def parse_assembly(self, response):
        print('parse_assembly')
        assembly = response.css('select#Content_AssemblyList > option::attr(value)')[1].extract()
        assembly_name = response.css('select#Content_AssemblyList > option::text')[1].extract()
        assembly_path = os.path.join(response.meta['district_path'], assembly_name.replace(' ', '_'))
        os.mkdir(assembly_path)
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET' : response.css('select#Content_AssemblyList::attr(name)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
            '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
            '__VIEWSTATE' : response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : response.meta['district'],
            'ctl00$Content$AssemblyList' : assembly,
            'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : ''
        }
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        request = scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], method='POST', formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.parse_part)
        request.meta['district'] = response.meta['district']
        request.meta['assembly'] = assembly
        request.meta['assembly_path'] = assembly_path
        yield request

    def parse_part(self, response):
        print('parse_part')
        part = response.css('select#Content_PartList > option::attr(value)')[1].extract()
        part_name = response.css('select#Content_PartList > option::text')[1].extract()
        part_path = os.path.join(response.meta['assembly_path'], part_name.replace(' ', '_'))
        os.mkdir(part_path)
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET' : response.css('select#Content_PartList::attr(name)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
            '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
            '__VIEWSTATE' : response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : response.meta['district'],
            'ctl00$Content$AssemblyList' : response.meta['assembly'],
            'ctl00$Content$PartList' : part,
            'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : ''
        }
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        request = scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], method='POST', formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.parse_captcha)
        request.meta['__VIEWSTATE'] = response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first()
        request.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first()
        request.meta['district'] = response.meta['district']
        request.meta['assembly'] = response.meta['assembly']
        request.meta['part'] = part
        request.meta['part_path'] = part_path
        yield request

    def parse_captcha(self, response):
        data_for_later = response
        request = scrapy.Request(url='https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/Captcha.aspx', callback=self.store_image)
        request.meta['__VIEWSTATE'] = response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first()
        request.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first()
        request.meta['district'] = response.meta['district']
        request.meta['assembly'] = response.meta['assembly']
        request.meta['part'] = response.meta['part']
        request.meta['part_path'] = response.meta['part_path']
        request.meta['data_for_later'] = data_for_later
        yield request

    def store_image(self, response):
        captcha_target_filename = 'filename.png'
        # save the image for processing
        i = Image.open(BytesIO(response.body))
        i.save(captcha_target_filename)
        captcha_text = self.solve_captcha(captcha_target_filename)
        print(captcha_text)
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET' : '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
            '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
            '__VIEWSTATE' : response.meta['__VIEWSTATE'],
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.meta['__EVENTVALIDATION'],
            'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : response.meta['district'],
            'ctl00$Content$AssemblyList' : response.meta['assembly'],
            'ctl00$Content$PartList' : response.meta['part'],
            'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : captcha_text,
            'ctl00$Content$OpenButton': 'Open PDF'
        }
        captcha_form = response.meta['data_for_later']
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        request = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(captcha_form, method='POST', formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.get_pdf_list)
        request.meta['district'] = response.meta['district']
        request.meta['assembly'] = response.meta['assembly']
        request.meta['part'] = response.meta['part']
        request.meta['part_path'] = response.meta['part_path']
        request.meta['data_for_later'] = captcha_form
        yield request

    def get_pdf_list(self, response):
        print('get_pdf_list')
        data_for_later = response
        pdf_content = response.meta['data_for_later']
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        for th, td in zip(response.css('table#Content_gvRollPDF > tr > th'), response.css('table#Content_gvRollPDF  tr > td')):
            data = {
                '__EVENTTARGET' : td.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first().split("'")[1],
                '__VIEWSTATE' : response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
                '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
                'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : response.meta['district'],
                'ctl00$Content$AssemblyList': response.meta['assembly'],
                'ctl00$Content$PartList': response.meta['part']
            }
            print(td.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first().split("'")[1])
            request = scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], method='POST', formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.download_pdf)
            request.meta['pdf_name'] = th.css('::text').extract_first()
            request.meta['part_path'] = response.meta['part_path']
            yield request

    def download_pdf(self, response):
        print('download_pdf')
        request = scrapy.Request(url='https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/ViewRoll.aspx', callback=self.pdf_data, dont_filter=True)
        request.meta['pdf_name'] = response.meta['pdf_name']
        request.meta['part_path'] = response.meta['part_path']
        yield request

    def pdf_data(self, response):
        path = os.path.join(response.meta['part_path'], response.meta['pdf_name'].replace(' ', '_') + '.pdf')
        filename = Path(path)
        filename.write_bytes(response.body)
        print(path)

    def solve_captcha(self, image):
        image = cv2.imread(image,0)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
        close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

        result = 255 - close
        cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
        cv2.imshow('close', close)
        cv2.imshow('result', result)

        return pytesseract.image_to_string(result)
```

Kindly find the below scrapy log:

```
(base) D:\Projects\GitHub\election_data>scrapy runspider election_data\spiders\election.py
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: election_data)
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.4.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.0, Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG': True, 'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'election_data', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'election_data.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['election_data.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'}
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 705359b7d6b3b682
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle']
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 5000 ms (+0) | latency:   82 ms | size:  1245 bytes
2019-09-15 02:28:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-09-15 02:28:42 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (-2000) | latency:   49 ms | size:  3961 bytes
2019-09-15 02:28:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx> (referer: None)
2019-09-15 02:28:47 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:   88 ms | size:  4877 bytes
2019-09-15 02:28:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
parse_assembly
2019-09-15 02:28:50 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:  116 ms | size: 20054 bytes
2019-09-15 02:28:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
parse_part
2019-09-15 02:28:55 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:  439 ms | size: 20050 bytes
2019-09-15 02:28:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
2019-09-15 02:28:59 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:   43 ms | size:  3965 bytes
2019-09-15 02:28:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/Captcha.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
cDDmt8
2019-09-15 02:29:04 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:  824 ms | size: 20576 bytes
2019-09-15 02:29:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/Captcha.aspx)
get_pdf_list
ctl00$Content$gvRollPDF$ctl02$MRollLink
ctl00$Content$gvRollPDF$ctl02$SupplementsLink
ctl00$Content$gvRollPDF$ctl02$SupplementsTwoLink
2019-09-15 02:29:07 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:  178 ms | size: 20639 bytes
2019-09-15 02:29:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
download_pdf
2019-09-15 02:29:10 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:   83 ms | size: 20639 bytes
2019-09-15 02:29:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
download_pdf
2019-09-15 02:29:13 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:   84 ms | size: 20639 bytes
2019-09-15 02:29:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
download_pdf
2019-09-15 02:29:18 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:  569 ms | size:155714 bytes
2019-09-15 02:29:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/ViewRoll.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
D:\Projects\GitHub\election_data\data\Ahmednagar\216_-_Akole_(ST)\1_-_Pachpathawadi\Mother_Roll.pdf
2019-09-15 02:29:22 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:  462 ms | size:155714 bytes
2019-09-15 02:29:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/ViewRoll.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
D:\Projects\GitHub\election_data\data\Ahmednagar\216_-_Akole_(ST)\1_-_Pachpathawadi\supplementary_2.pdf
2019-09-15 02:29:25 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: ceo.maharashtra.gov.in | conc: 1 | delay: 3000 ms (+0) | latency:  454 ms | size:155714 bytes
2019-09-15 02:29:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/ViewRoll.aspx> (referer: https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/SearchRollPDF.aspx)
D:\Projects\GitHub\election_data\data\Ahmednagar\216_-_Akole_(ST)\1_-_Pachpathawadi\supplementary_1.pdf
2019-09-15 02:29:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-09-15 02:29:25 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 103807,
 'downloader/request_count': 13,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 7,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 607088,
 'downloader/response_count': 13,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 12,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 14, 20, 59, 25, 458688),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 13,
 'log_count/INFO': 22,
 'request_depth_max': 7,
 'response_received_count': 13,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 12,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 12,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 12,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 12,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 14, 20, 58, 36, 817768)}
2019-09-15 02:29:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Kindly help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that every request for downloading a PDF is changing the ASP session state. So in order to download all PDFs, you need to do the downloading sequentially:

1. create request for downloading PDF 1
2. make sure you updated cookies etc that came with the PDF download
3. create request for downloading PDF 2
   ... etc

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but I don't know how to convert those steps into the code. And also whether that will work or not, I am not sure. Using `yield` causes problem I think. If there is a way to "sequentially"(the way we can call a function inside a loop for each iteration and until the execution of function doesn't end, it won't iterate further) handle this in Scrapy, then this couldn't be a problem. For more information, I am adding log details, which shows messages I printed in each scrapy method.

Comment: Any idea about this https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order ?

Comment: Ok, now I have come so close and your advice helped me a lot in finding this solution. According to this https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider, we can separate cookie sessions for different spiders. And that really helped in this.

Comment: But still, there is one issue I am facing and that is it is not giving me pdf files in a consistent manner. I mean, for some pages I get all the pdfs but for some, I don't. Sometimes it gives all the pdf files. So, it is not consistent. I don't know what is the exact problem and how to debug in this scrapy architecture. I think I'll need help for scrapy core developer here or of someone who knows in-out of Scrapy. If you can input your expertise here, I'll be glad. Thanks anyway.